# How to expose ports between docker images in different sub-networks?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have created two docker networks:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.1.0.0/16 --ip-range=172.1.5.0/24 --gateway=172.1.5.254 br1


docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.2.0.0/16 --ip-range=172.2.5.0/24 --gateway=172.2.5.254 br2
```

I am doing this in order to facilitate easier container interactions within that network (I do not need to expose ports for containers within that subnet).

Now however, I am interested in networking a few services between my two subnets within Docker (perhaps A as 172.1.0.0 and B as 172.2.0.0).

How can I expose a port so that they can connect to each other between the two subnets? Previous to making the docker subnet, I could just use `-p 8000:8000` to expose ports when I ran docker images and then have access the required port.

I am using docker version 1.10.1 and docker-machine.

---

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#a-bridge-network) suggests this is possible but gives no real examples:

> Within a user-defined bridge network, linking is not supported. You can expose and publish container ports on containers in this network. This is useful if you want to make a portion of the bridge network available to an outside network.
>   [image]

Comment: Why can't you continue using `-p`?

Comment: @PreferenceBean the connection no longer works (when using that configuration as above). I _suspect_ it has to do with the reasons listed in the documentation, that they are intentionally isolated from each other when running in a subnet.

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, looks pretty clear. You'd have to bounce traffic off a node on the outside.

Comment: Does this external_container is hosted in another network outside your container1-Docker_host-LAN? If so it is a NAT/PAT issue.